# How to handle partially dynamic JSON with Swift Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I've got some JSON messages coming in over a websocket connection.

```
// sample message
{
  type: "person",
  data: {
    name: "john"
  }
}

// some other message
{
  type: "location",
  data: {
    x: 101,
    y: 56
  }
}
```

How can I convert those messages into proper structs using Swift 4 and the Codable protocol?

In Go I can do something like: "Hey at the moment I only care about the `type` field and I'm not interested in the rest (the `data` part)." It would look like this

```
type Message struct {
  Type string `json:"type"`
  Data json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}
```

As you can see `Data` is of type `json.RawMessage` which can be parsed later on. Here is a full example https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage_unmarshal.

Can I do something similar in Swift? Like (haven't tried it yet)

```
struct Message: Codable {
  var type: String
  var data: [String: Any]
}
```

Then `switch` on the `type` to convert the dictionary into proper structs. Would that work?

Comment: Check this file: https://github.com/iwheelbuy/VK/blob/master/VK/Core/Object/Attachment/VK_Object_Attachment.swift

Comment: FYI, your JSON examples are missing quotation marks around `type`, `data`, `name`, `x` and `y`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I wouldn't rely upon a `Dictionary`. I'd use custom types.

For example, let's assume that:

- you know which object you're going to get back (because of the nature of the request); and
- the two types of response truly return identical structures except the contents of the `data`.

In that case, you might use a very simple generic pattern:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}

struct ServerResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let data: T
}
```

And then, when you want to parse a response with a `Person`, it would be:

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse<Person>.self, from: data)

    let person = responseObject.data
    print(person)
} catch let parseError {
    print(parseError)
}
```

Or to parse a `Location`:

```
do {
    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse<Location>.self, from: data)

    let location = responseObject.data
    print(location)
} catch let parseError {
    print(parseError)
}
```

There are more complicated patterns one could entertain (e.g. dynamic parsing of the `data` type based upon the `type` value it encountered), but I wouldn't be inclined to pursue such patterns unless necessary. This is a nice, simple approach that accomplishes typical pattern where you know the associated response type for a particular request.

---

If you wanted you could validate the `type` value with what was parsed from the `data` value. Consider:

```
enum PayloadType: String, Decodable {
    case person = "person"
    case location = "location"
}

protocol Payload: Decodable {
    static var payloadType: PayloadType { get }
}

struct Person: Payload {
    let name: String
    static let payloadType = PayloadType.person
}

struct Location: Payload {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    static let payloadType = PayloadType.location
}

struct ServerResponse<T: Payload>: Decodable {
    let type: PayloadType
    let data: T
}
```

Then, your `parse` function could not only parse the right `data` structure, but confirm the `type` value, e.g.:

```
enum ParseError: Error {
    case wrongPayloadType
}

func parse<T: Payload>(_ data: Data) throws -> T {
    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse<T>.self, from: data)

    guard responseObject.type == T.payloadType else {
        throw ParseError.wrongPayloadType
    }

    return responseObject.data
}
```

And then you could call it like so:

```
do {
    let location: Location = try parse(data)
    print(location)
} catch let parseError {
    print(parseError)
}
```

That not only returns the `Location` object, but also validates the value for `type` in the server response. I'm not sure it's worth the effort, but in case you wanted to do so, that's an approach.

---

If you really don't know the type when processing the JSON, then you just need to write an `init(coder:)` that first parses the `type`, and then parses the `data` depending upon the value that `type` contained:

```
enum PayloadType: String, Decodable {
    case person = "person"
    case location = "location"
}

protocol Payload: Decodable {
    static var payloadType: PayloadType { get }
}

struct Person: Payload {
    let name: String
    static let payloadType = PayloadType.person
}

struct Location: Payload {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    static let payloadType = PayloadType.location
}

struct ServerResponse: Decodable {
    let type: PayloadType
    let data: Payload

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type = try values.decode(PayloadType.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case .person:
            data = try values.decode(Person.self, forKey: .data)
        case .location:
            data = try values.decode(Location.self, forKey: .data)
        }
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, data
    }

}
```

And then you can do things like:

```
do {
    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResponse.self, from: data)
    let payload = responseObject.data
    if payload is Location {
        print("location:", payload)
    } else if payload is Person {
        print("person:", payload)
    }
} catch let parseError {
    print(parseError)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. The problem is that I do not know the type of the incoming message. It is not request/response based but a websocket connection. The messages itself are all equal having `type` and `data` keys.

Comment: Then you will need to write an `init(coder:)` that first parses the `type`, and then parses the `data` as the corresponding type. See expanded answer above.

Comment: Thanks again! And Happy New Year! It works and I've got a stable websocket communication between ios <-> golang <-> js. However my `payload` in the final `if` clause if always of type `Payload`. Therefore I cannot do something like (in case it is `Location`) `print(payload.x)`. How do I get real types instead of protocols?

Comment: `if let person = payload as? Person { ... }` or `if let location = payload as? Location { ... }`

Comment: Please look into this and give your opinion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181230/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-key-which-holds-dynamic-object-using-codable

Comment: @Rob so how to manage case when "type" is returned everytime, and based on that type next codingKey would be instead of "data" with a generic pattern? i.e. `{ type: "location", location: {x:1, y:1}}` ?

Comment: The Best! Thanks for sharing the good implementation case for this situation. It's great!