# How to decode a nested json key which holds dynamic object using codable

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I am getting some web response in the below format, The problem is `testMap` is of dynamic type. Key of the object as well as the data type is dynamic. testMap will be a dictionary type object, which'll contain dynamic data in its dynamic key. As you can see, it can be string, array of string or array of integers.

```
{"results": [
  {"tests": [{
        "testsType": "A",
        "testMap": {
          "testId": "5a7c4fedec7fb72b7aa9b36e"}}]
  },
  {
    "tests": [{
        "testsType": "B",
        "testMap": {
          "myIds": ["2112"]}}]
  }]
}
```

I tried to [use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726415/using-codable-on-a-dynamic-type-object?noredirect=1#comment80406088_46726415) but It didn't work cause the value type is unknown in my case. `testMap:[String:Any]` didn't work, cause `Any` doesn't conform to `Codable`.

**Model**

```
struct Results: Codable
{
 let results: [Tests]
}
 struct Tests: Codable
{
 let tests: [Test]
}
 struct Test: Codable
{
 let testsType: String?
 var testMap:[String:String] // Its wrong, cause value type is unknown
}
```

Comment: I must say that this `TestMap` entity that I introduced below, where both `testId` and `myIds` are optionals, feels like code smell for some deeper problem in the structure of the JSON, namely that `testMap` key really seems to be referring to two different types of objects, a `testId` and an array of `myIds`. I don't know what function these various key/value pairs really serve, so it's hard to counsel you further, but IMHO, when you find yourself creating arbitrary bottom level objects in order to parse, there's really a deeper problem in the original JSON.

Comment: Actually this response is structure of some search response, which is based on multiple query. Its in this way, cause we have made the search generic, in overall application. This is not the actual response, its just the example of my JSON format to make things readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will decode your JSON:

```
struct Results: Codable {
    let results: [Tests]
}

struct Tests: Codable {
    let tests: [Test]
}

struct Test: Codable {
    let testsType: String
    let testMap: TestMap
}

struct TestMap: Codable {
    let testId: String?
    let myIds: [String]?
}
```

And, obviously:

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Actually `testMap` is dynamic, I don't know about the key name. In example its `testId` and `myIds` but it can be anything and also the value and type of `testMap`  is unknown.

Comment: key `testMap` will be known always, but not the type of its content. Do you think, for this scenario I should use simple JSONSerialization without Codable.

Comment: Yeah, especially when the structure of the value associated with that key is not consistent. You can write custom `init(from:)` methods, but with something like this, where the structure is allegedly completely dynamic and unpredicatable, `JSONSerialization` might just be easier.

Comment: For now I am using `JSONSerialization` but give it a shot using `Codable` when you get some time.