# Decoding dynamic JSON structure in swift 4

Tags: swift, decodable

I have the following issue that I'm not sure how to handle.

My `JSON` response can look like this:

```
{ 
  "data": {
      "id": 7,
      "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NDY1MTU0NDMsImRhdGEiOiJ2bGFkVGVzdCIsImlhdCI6MTU0NjUwODI0M30.uwuPhlnchgBG4E8IvHvK4bB1Yj-TNDgmi7wUAiKmoVo"
   },
  "error": null
}
```

Or like this:

```
{
 "data": [{
     "id": 12
    }, {
      "id": 2
    }, {
       "id": 5
    }, {
       "id": 7
    }],
 "error": null
}
```

So in short the data can be either a single objet or an Array. What i have is this:

```
struct ApiData: Decodable {
    var data: DataObject?
    var error: String?
}

struct DataObject: Decodable {
    var userId: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userId = "id"
    }
}
```

This works fine for the first use case, but it will fail once data turns into

`var data: [DataObject?]`

How do I make that dynamic without duplicating code?

Edit: This is how i decode the object as well

```
 func makeDataTaskWith(with urlRequest: URLRequest, completion: @escaping(_ apiData: ApiData?) -> ()) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard let _ = response, let data = data else {return}

        if let responseCode = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Response has status code: \(responseCode.statusCode)")
        }

        do {
            let retreived = try NetworkManager.shared.decoder.decode(ApiData.self, from: data)
            completion(retreived)
        } catch let decodeError as NSError {
            print("Decoder error: \(decodeError.localizedDescription)\n")
            return
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: And what does the API send in case of `error != null`?

Comment: @vadian it sends a string, u can see that in the ApiData structure.

Comment: @RobertDresler I'm not sure i understand the question? With the help of the struct ApiData that conforms to decodable protocol

Comment: @RobertDresler i've edited the post to answer your question.

Comment: Use power of generic

Comment: See-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674899/6630644

Answer (score 3):

If `data` can be a single object or an array write a custom initializer which decodes first an array, if a type mismatch error occurs decode a single object. `data` is declared as an array anyway.

As `token` appears only in a single object the property is declared as optional.

```
struct ApiData: Decodable {
    let data : [DataObject]
    let error : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case data, error }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            data = try container.decode([DataObject].self, forKey: .data)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            data = [try container.decode(DataObject.self, forKey: .data)]
        }
        error = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .error)
    }
}


struct DataObject: Decodable {
    let userId : Int
    let token : String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case userId = "id", token }
}
```

Edit: Your code to receive the data can be improved. You should add a better error handling to return also all possible errors:

```
func makeDataTaskWith(with urlRequest: URLRequest, completion: @escaping(ApiData?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error { completion(nil, error); return }

        if let responseCode = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Response has status code: \(responseCode.statusCode)")
        }

        do {
            let retreived = try NetworkManager.shared.decoder.decode(ApiData.self, from: data!)
            completion(retreived, nil)
        } catch {
            print("Decoder error: ", error)
            completion(nil, error)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, didn't know of DecodingError.typeMismatch. Thank you!

Comment: You always nailed answer when it comes to Codable 

Answer (score 2):

Using power of `generic`, it simple like below:

```
struct ApiData<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    var data: T?
    var error: String?
}

struct DataObject: Decodable {
    private var id: Int?

    var userId:Int? {
        return id
    }
}
```

**Use**

```
if let obj = try? NetworkManager.shared.decoder.decode(ApiData<DataObject>.self, from: data) {
    //Do somthing
} else if let array = try NetworkManager.shared.decoder.decode(ApiData<[DataObject]>.self, from: data) {
    // Do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two possible outcomes for your data, an option would be to try and parse data to one of the expected types, if that fails you know that the data is of other type and you can then handle it accordingly.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007761/how-to-handle-partially-dynamic-json-with-swift-codable?rq=1)

Comment: Yes but that would duplicate code, both types would have  var userId: Int? and a bunch of other user info that i've not pasted in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: DataUnion
    let error: String?
}

enum DataUnion: Codable {
    case dataClass(DataClass)
    case datumArray([Datum])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([Datum].self) {
            self = .datumArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(DataClass.self) {
            self = .dataClass(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(DataUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for DataUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .dataClass(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .datumArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let id: Int
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let token: String
}
```

---

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't avoid duplication. Both structs Datum and DataClass have let id.

Comment: you can make them 1 but should make token optional if you want